# Does $\sum a_n$ converge in this case?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given an arbitrary series $a_n$, if $|s_n| \leq 5 \forall n$, then does $\sum a_n$ converge? I have a counterexample here, don't know if it's valid or not, but let $a_n = (-1)^{n}$, then $a_n$ diverges. Alternatively, take $a_n=-100n$.

Comment: Note that the question is basically asking, if $b_n$ is a sequence (that happens to be a sequence of partial sums) and $|b_n| \leq 5$ holds for all $n$, does $b_n$ converge. The answer is no, as your first example points out. If your $a_n$ were a sequence of nonnegative numbers, then the sequence $s_n$ of partial sums would be monotone increasing, and boundedness of a monotone increasing sequence does imply convergence. But that isn't what you asked.

Comment: "Given an arbitrary series", do you mean sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first counterexample is valid, as it just take value $1$ and $0$.

The second one is not valid, as the magnitude increases.